# How to create file with google-cloud-storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

In my Rails project, I use `gem 'google-cloud-storage'` and `gem 'aws-sdk-s3'`.

To create a file using AWS, I use following code:

```
connection = Fog::Storage.new({
               provider: 'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] })

directory = connection.directories.get(ENV['AWS_BUCKET'])

file = directory.files.create(
                    key: some_filename,
           content_type: some_type,
                   body: some_body,
                 public: true )
```

Is there a way to also create a file using gcloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understood problem.

To create a file, you need to use `create_file` method

```
def create_file file, path = nil, acl: nil, cache_control: nil,
                content_disposition: nil, content_encoding: nil,
                content_language: nil, content_type: nil,
                crc32c: nil, md5: nil, metadata: nil,
                encryption_key: nil, encryption_key_sha256: nil
  ensure_service!
  options = { acl: File::Acl.predefined_rule_for(acl), md5: md5,
              cache_control: cache_control, content_type: content_type,
              content_disposition: content_disposition, crc32c: crc32c,
              content_encoding: content_encoding,
              content_language: content_language, metadata: metadata,
              key: encryption_key, key_sha256: encryption_key_sha256 }
  ensure_file_exists! file

  path ||= Pathname(file).to_path
  gapi = service.insert_file name, file, path, options
  File.from_gapi gapi, service
end
```

In my case, I load sound by creating a tempfile and then put this tempfile in method.

```
storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new(project: ENV['GOOGLE_ID'], 
                                     keyfile: ENV['GOOGLE_JSON'] )

bucket = storage.bucket( ENV['GOOGLE_BUCKET'] )

bucket.create_file(sound.tempfile, some_filename)
```